# Why can $st\left(\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}\right)=st\left(\frac{\Delta u}{\Delta x}\right)+st\left(\frac{\Delta v}{\Delta x}\right)$ be written as

Tags: differential, nonstandard-analysis

> Why can $st \left(\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}\right)=st \left(\frac{\Delta u}{\Delta x}\right)+st \left(\frac{\Delta v}{\Delta x}\right)$ be written as $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{du}{dx}+\frac{dv}{dx}$?

This is taken from Elementary Calculus: an infinitesimal approach. You can see a picture illustrating the origin of my "problem":

[image]

Help appreciated, as I cannot see what happened.

Comment: This is just the definition of each derivative: the standard part of an appropriate quotient.

Comment: Take a look at starting pages of the chapter it is given $st\left(\Delta y/\Delta x\right)= dy/dx$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If  $y$ can be expressed as a function of $x$, say $y = f(x)$, then you have previously defined

$$ f'(x) = \operatorname{st}\left( \frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x} \right) $$

$$ dy = f'(x) dx $$

from which it follows

$$ \frac{dy}{dx} = \operatorname{st}\left( \frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x} \right) $$